# What is the average or above-average score range for the AMC 1o and AIME?

Tags: contest-math

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but what is the average/above-average score range for the AMC 10 and AIME? For example, what points would you say are below-average, average, above-average, and top-of-the-line?

As a starter, I'd say 120 for the AMC 10 is above-average because it's the AIME cutoff.

Comment: Seems to me that you can find statistics here: http://amc-reg.maa.org/reports/generalreports.aspx

Comment: In particular for AMC 10 120 looks quite above average (eyeballing 1-2 standard deviations above)

Comment: oh wait, it tells me mean and standard deviation. It's actually the nearest thing to 2 standard deviations above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to the link Peter Woolfitt placed, we can find the following:

- Over the past 6 AMC competitions, the average score is between 60 and 75. With 120 you are almost always in the top 2.5%, and in half of the cases its enough to get you in that top 1%. I'd say that 100 is already above average, i.e. at least in the top 20%.
- AIME, I'd say that 5.0 is average, 3.0 is below average, 8.0 is above average, and 13.0 is the top, i.e. probably in the top 1%.